How to group by name and sum times in Power Query
Context: I extracted raw data from a clock in/out system, which shows me the time people went in or out of the office. I need to transform the data so I can calculate some statistics and charts.
Input: The last step of my Power Query look like this:



Name
DateIn
AM_PM
TimeMin
TimeMax
AM_In_raw
AM_Out_raw
PM_In_raw
PM_Out_raw




Pablo
29/4/2024
AM
08:27:21
12:22:01
08:27:21
12:22:01
00:00:00
00:00:00


Pablo
29/4/2024
PM
14:13:02
19:16:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
14:13:02
19:16:00


Pablo
30/4/2024
AM
08:09:15
12:17:24
08:09:15
12:17:24
00:00:00
00:00:00


Pablo
30/4/2024
PM
14:17:28
18:06:04
00:00:00
00:00:00
14:17:28
18:06:04



Desired Output: I want to group rows by Name and Date and sum the time columns, so the in/out times are in one row for each Name and date. It should look like this:



Name
DateIn
AM_In
AM_Out
PM_In
PM_Out




Pablo
29/4/2024
08:27:21
12:22:01
14:13:02
19:16:00


Pablo
30/4/2024
08:09:15
12:17:24
14:17:28
18:06:04



Problem: When I try to sum dates (aggregate) I get "error" in most cells.
= Table.Group(#"Filtered Pablo", {"Name", "Date"}, 
{{"AM_In", each List.Sum([AM_In_raw]), type any}, 
{"AM_Out", each List.Sum([AM_Out_raw]), type any}, 
{"PM_In", each List.Sum([PM_In_raw]), type any}, 
{"PM_Out", each List.Sum([PM_Out_raw]), type any}})

Question: What is a good way to combine multiple rows into only one that contains all the valid values using Power Query in Excel?
Thanks in advance for any clue leading to a working solution. If there is a best practice or technique to solve this type of problem in different scenarios it would be greatly appreciated.
SQL or Python solutions are also welcomed.
